# JBoss Application server heap space issues - how often should I restart

Tags: jboss, heap-memory

We are currently running JBoss Application server 5.0, we are running into heap space issues, how often should we restart the application server? and why does the server run into heap space errors. Our application mostly has documents submitted to it, which can go upto 500 MB/day.

Comment: If you have heap space issue then it will be memory leak in your application. take heap dump and check what is taking too much space. you can use MAT to analyze heap dump.

Comment: "How often should we restart the application server ? " 
Server in general don't need to get restarted to function properly. if you have heap space issue it could very well because of memory leak, or you did not set the memory right. Saying documents submitted 500MB / day does not say anything about how much your current heap size is or should be. It depends on various factors. Don't use the resort of restarting the server as a fix of application bugs ( memory leak issues ).